# how can I update the org-mode header-args from the output of an org-babel code block?

Tags: org-babel

I have a code block with a shell scripts that asks for a token. I want to insert this token into the header-args, so that I can reference this from other code blocks.

I usually copy it, but can this be done with code?;)

Comment: Use `:var token=foo` where foo is the name of the code block that produces the token.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```shell
#+name: generate
#+begin_src shell 
  #generate-token
  echo "Super-secret-token-ABC"
#+end_src


#+name: use-token
#+begin_src shell :var token=generate
  echo command-that-needs-to-authenticate --token=${token}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: use-token
: command-that-needs-to-authenticate --token=Super-secret-token-ABC
```

Comment: Did you see this? Did it work for you? I don't understand why you are so reluctant to provide feedback (accept, upvote, downvote, or even just a comment indicating the outcome). That's part of how this site is supposed to work.